# Jenkinsfile Groovy code not allowing me to call class contructor

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
   boolean mySetting
   String mySetting2
   List<String> mySetting3
   ...etc for another 10...
}
```

but when I try to call its constructor with what look like valid values, I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException **with no message**.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2725)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3770)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:1747)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$NoParamSite.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onNewInstance(GroovyInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:173)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:205)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedConstructor(Checker.java:210)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.constructorCall(SandboxInvoker.java:21)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:116)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
```

I'd like to make it known publically that I hate Groovy and Jenkins could have been a reasonable system without it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I changed my code to set all the parameters individually and discovered that one hadn't been set. This had obviously worked in all my PRs because the params object had default values defined already but not in my new branch because it was the first time it was run.

I changed my line to this:

`myObj.mySetting = params.setting || false`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2725)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3770)
    at ExecutionConfiguration.setProperty(WorkflowScript)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.setProperty(InvokerHelper.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:484)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$8.call(Checker.java:412)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onSetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onSetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:229)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$8.call(Checker.java:409)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedSetProperty(Checker.java:416)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.setProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:33)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawSet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:24)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:131)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
```